# Converting associative array request parameters to JSON with Jackson

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I am the recipient of a webhook POST that looks like this, which I have decoded for readability.

```
id=12345&event=this_event&payload[customer][name]=ABC Company&payload[customer][city]=New York&payload[service][name]=New Customer&payload[service][action]=New
```

Using Spring MVC, I can easily get this into a `Map<String, Sting>` that looks like this

```
{id=97659204, event=test, payload[customer][name]=ABC Company, payload[customer][city]=New York, payload[service][name]=New Customer, payload[service][action]=New}
```

I need to parse every parameter (or Map key) that starts with "payload" into a JSON object.

My desired output from parsing the request parameters that start with "payload" would look something like this

```
{
    customer :  {
        name : "ABC Company",
        city : "New York"
    },
    service : {
        name : "New Customer",
        action : "New"
    }
}
```

With the final state being a call to Jackson's ObjectMapper to turn that JSON into a POJO.

Since I have no control over the data format begin sent to me, what is the best/correct option for parsing those request parameters into a JSON object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a custom parser for the payload[][][] parameters being passed in.  It uses regex matcher and then recursion to analyze each parameter, traverse a Map of 1...n Maps and then the resulting Map makes perfect JSON.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/receiver", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void receiver(@RequestParam Map<String, Object> requestBody) throws IOException {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\]]+)]");

    Map<String, Object> payloadMap = new HashMap<>();
    Matcher matcher = null;
    List<String> levels = null;

    for (String key : requestBody.keySet()) {

        if (key.startsWith("payload")) {

            matcher = pattern.matcher(key);
            levels = new ArrayList<>();
            while (matcher.find()) {
                levels.add(matcher.group(1));
            }

            payloadMap = nestMap(payloadMap, levels.iterator(), (String) requestBody.get(key));

        }
    }

    LOG.debug(mapper.writeValueAsString(payloadMap));

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private Map<String, Object> nestMap(Map<String, Object> baseMap, Iterator<String> levels, String value) {

    String key = levels.next();

    if (!levels.hasNext()) {
        baseMap.put(key, value);
    } else {
        if (!baseMap.containsKey(key)) {
            baseMap.put(key, nestMap(new HashMap<String, Object>(), levels, value));
        } else {
            baseMap.put(key, nestMap((Map<String, Object>) baseMap.get(key), levels, value));
        }
    }

    return baseMap;

}
```